# Jquery remember last selected tab using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabLink").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        tabeId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
        $("#"+tabeId+"-1").removeClass("hide")   
        return false;     
      });
    });  
  });
</script>
```

i am trying to make it so the tab is remembered if the page is refreshed by using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabLink").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).index() + 1;
        tabeId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
        $("#"+tabeId+"-1").removeClass("hide")   
        return false;     
      });
    });  

    // search for local storage
    if (localStorage.selectedTab) {
      $(".tabLink:eq(" + (localStorage.selectedTab - 1) + ")").click();
    }
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-box">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink activeLink" id="viewcustomer">View Customer</a> 
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink activeLink" id="viewresellercustomers">View Reseller Customer</a> 
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink activeLink" id="viewsalesmancustomer">View Salesman Customer</a> 
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink" id="archivedcustomers">View Archived Customer</a> 
        </div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="viewcustomer-1">
content...
</div>.....
```

it works fine, but the tabs are on multiple pages so if i go to a different page, a different tab is selected as its trying to remember the last selected tab.

how can i make it remember the last selected tab for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) to persist the selection :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function activate(tab) {
        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        tab.addClass("active");

        // slide all content up
        $(".content").slideUp();

        // slide this content up
        var content_show = tab.attr("title");
        $("#" + content_show).slideDown();
    }

    if (localStorage) { // let's not crash if some user has IE7
        var index = parseInt(localStorage['tab'] || '0');
        activate($('a.tab').eq(index));
    }

    // When a link is clicked
    $("a.tab").click(function () {
        if (localStorage) localStorage['tab'] = $(this).closest('li').index();
        activate($(this));
    });

});
```

Comment: How does it solve the problem of retrieving last selected tab individually for each page?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map linking URLs to selected tabs, like

```
tabStorage = { 
 "page_url_1" : 1,
 "page_url_2" : 3
}
```

You can get the URL of current page using `winow.location`.

Then to save/retrieve it use `JSON.stringify` / `JSON.parse`, because `localStorage` only keeps key/value pairs, not objects. The key here is 'tabs', the value - a strigified representation of the map.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tabStorage = (localStorage && localStorage.tabs) ? JSON.parse( localStorage.tabs ) : {};
   $(".tabLink").click(function(){
      tabStorage[ window.location ] =  $(".tabLink").index( this );
      if(localStorage) {
          localStorage.tabs = JSON.stringify( tabStorage );
      }
   });

   if (tabStorage[ window.location ]) {
      $(".tabLink").eq( tabStorage[ window.location ] ).trigger('click');
   }
});
```